# Find perpendicular height of triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Consider a triangle $\triangle ABC$. It is given that angle $A\hat{B}C$ is 38 degrees, angle $A\hat{C}B$ is 62 degrees, the length of $\overline{BC}$ is 38 cm. Find the perpendicular height of the triangle (from A to the base BC).

I can solve this with the use of Sine Rule. But is there another way to solve this question without using Sine Rule?

Comment: why don't you want to use the sine rule.  You can't solve it without trig.  The sine rule would be the easiest and most straightforward way.

Comment: If you try to solve it without using the sine law, you'll end up deriving the sine law.

Answer (score 0):

Let the perpendicular from A onto the side BC meets BC at the point D.
Let the length BD be $x$ cm. Therefore, CD becomes $(38-x)$ cm.

Now, tangent of angle ABC (which is 38 degrees) = $AD/BD$ = $AD/x$ ....... (1)

Also, tangent of angle ACB (which is 62 degrees) = $AD/CD$ = $AD/(38-x)$ ..... (2)

Now, equate the value of AD from equation (1) and equation (2) to get the value of x as $26.85$ cm, approximately. Put this back in equation (1) to get $AD = 20.98$ cm, approximately, which is what you wanted!

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted a solution which would not involve computing those trigonometric ratios. :\

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> $\angle ABC=\beta=38^\circ$,  $\angle ACB=\gamma=62^\circ$, 
>   $|BC|=a=38$cm, $D\in BC,\ AD\perp BC$  Find $|AD|=h_a$

Known formula for the area of triangle
in terms of given side length and two adjacent angles
is
\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac12\,a^2\,\frac{\sin\beta\sin\gamma}
{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}
,
\end{align}
on the other hand,
\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac12\,a\,h_a
,\\
\text{so }\quad
h_a&=a\,\frac{\sin\beta\sin\gamma}{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}
.
\end{align}

Comment: what did you use except sine rule?....$h_a$ was written using S.R.

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi: As stated, two 
known formula for the area of triangle:
one in terms of given side length and two adjacent angles,
and another, in terms of the base and the height.
And of course, the first one can be found 
with the help of the sine rule. 
since everything is connected in triangular world.

Comment: Yes, that's what am saying, probably the OP wanted something non-trivial/out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No sine(s) used:

\begin{align}
\triangle{ABD}:\quad
\tan\beta&=\frac h{|BD|}
,\quad \Rightarrow |BD|=h\,\cot\beta
,\\
\triangle{ADC}:\quad
\tan\gamma&=\frac h{|CD|}
,\quad \Rightarrow |CD|=h\,\cot\gamma
,\\
|BD|+|CD|&=|BC|
,\\
h\,\cot\beta+h\,\cot\gamma
&=|BC|
,\\
h&=\frac{|BC|}{\cot\beta+\cot\gamma}
.
\end{align}